# Character to date in R

Tags: r, date, character

One of the columns in my data frame is a character which has the following format (an example):

2013-02-05 08:00:00

Some of the rows are NULL in this column. I want to change the class to date format but I am getting NA for all rows.

Could you please tell me what should I do to make it work?

Comment: What happens if you type as.Date("2013-02-05 08:00:00") ?

Comment: `as.Date(2013-02-05 08:00:00)` returns `2013-02-05` of class date.

Comment: Install the `lubridate` package and try `library(lubridate); ymd_hms()` on the column you want to convert.

Comment: If you want to keep the time, try `as.POSIXct("2013-02-05 08:00:00")` (assuming the time is in your local time zone). By some rows are "NULL" do you mean "NA"? You can't store a NULL in an atomic vector. Can you please edit your question to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Actually, when I type as.Date(column name, format="%Y-%m-%d %h-%m-%s"), it gives me NA.

Comment: Please (1) share some of your data, (2) in a reproducible way, (3) in your question. The best way would be to post `dput(your_data$your_date_column)`, though `str(your_data$your_date_column)` would also work. If your data is larger than 20 rows or so, only post the first 20 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should install Hadley Wickham's [`lubridate`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html%20%60lubridate%60) package, and use:

```
> ymd_hms("2013-02-05 08:00:00")
```

The package includes many other functions that'll help you (safely) manipulate datetime and interval objects.

Comment: When I do this: Pact$CDT <- as.POSIXct(Pact$CDT) (assume that Pact is my data table and CDT is the column), I am getting the following error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, assuming your data frame is DF, and your date column (as character) DATE.STR, I would do the following:

```
DF$DATE=as.Date(DF$DATE.STR)
```

Of course, using lubridate would give you more options, but I think you can use base R for this.

Comment: I am getting the following error:  do not know how to convert 'DF$DATE.STR' to class “Date”.

Comment: Well, he is asking for a date.

Comment: But that column is a character. What can I do?

Comment: There is something wrong here, can you update your question and do a str(your data frame), and also give us some more lines of your dates?

Comment: The column's format is character and some of its cells are: NULL, 2011-11-04 08:34:00, 2012-01-03 14:49:36.

Comment: Ok, please update your question by giving some more info. do a dput, etc so we have an idea what your data frame is (@mrflick's comment above). I am surprised by the NULL...